# how to disable and enable button with condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a button and I want it to be active only if  'status' table in the database is accepted otherwise to be disabled
this is the code I tried
please help

```
<div class="col-md-5">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="nw_check" value="time in" <?php
    $uname= $_SESSION['uName'];

     <div class="col-md-5">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="nw_check" value="time in" <?php
    $uname= $_SESSION['uName'];

    $query="select * from optime where user_no='$uname'";
$Result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);

 if(isset($row['status'] )=='pending') && ($row['status']) == 'rejected'{
                ?> disable <?php }?>>



            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $disabled = '';
    $uname = $_SESSION['uName'];
    $query = "select * from optime where user_no='$uname'";
    $Result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);
    if(isset($row['status']) && ($row['status'] == 'rejected' || $row['status'] == 'pending')){
        $disabled = 'disabled';
    }
?>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="nw_check" value="time in" <?php echo $disabled; ?> />
</div>`
```

Comment: thanks but it is still not working. it is active for every status

Comment: help please i really need to get this done today and i cant go far without this

Comment: Please let me know the list of status.

Comment: In which status the button will be disabled ?

Comment: the status list is accepted, rejected and pending... pending is default

Comment: the button should be disabled if the status list is either pending or rejected

Comment: Please change the if statement as : if(isset($row['status']) && ($row['status'] == 'rejected' || $row['status'] == 'pending')){ $disabled = 'disabled'; }  . I have update my answer also. Please check.

Comment: wait  i thought it worked but itsnot. idont know whats wrong

Comment: only the pending status is disabled with that code. what about the reject?

Comment: SORRY it was my mistake your code works fine. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace && with || in if statement

if ($row['status'] == 'pending' || $row['status'] == 'rejected'){
    $disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: the disable is working but with that code it disables the button without any condition. the condition doesnot work

Comment: in if statement you can add whatever the status you want, for reference i have added pending/rejected status. But if you have different status you can replace that with pending/rejected

Comment: what i meant is it would be nice if for a condition of status=accepted  , the button could work because now for all conditions it is disabled. how can i make the button to work for that particular status the rest remaining as it is?

Comment: if you want to disable the button if status=accepted then, you can try this

    if($row['status']=='accepted') {
        $disabled = 'disabled';
    }

Comment: Then do this: if($row['status'] != 'accepted') { $disabled = 'disabled'; }